# How to make these lines shorter and not duplicating code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am duplicating alot of codes in my project. How can I refractory these lines and make it more shorter? Here is my following code in my project:

```
    const MobileManagement = (props) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const {
        editable,
        teamId,
        agreement,
        teamData,
        fetchTeamData,
        userPublicId,
        members,
        notify,
      } = props;
      const [openMission, setOpenMission] = useState(false);
      const rotate = openMission ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)";
    
      const [openAgreement, setOpenAgreement] = useState(false);
      const rotateAgreement = openAgreement ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)";
    
      const [openCalendar, setOpenCalendar] = useState(false);
      const rotateCalendar = openCalendar ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)";
    
      return (
        <div className={classes.mobileContainer}>
          <TeamOption>
            <TeamPage onClick={() => setOpenMission(!openMission)}>
              Mission
              <span
                className={classes.arrow}
                style={{ transform: rotate, transition: "all 0.2s linear" }}
              >
                <EditArrow />
              </span>
            </TeamPage>
            {openMission && (
              <Mission
                editable={editable}
                teamId={teamId}
                teamData={teamData}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
                notify={notify}
              />
            )}
            <TeamPage onClick={() => setOpenAgreement(!openAgreement)}>
              Agreement
              <span
                className={classes.arrow}
                style={{
                  transform: rotateAgreement,
                  transition: "all 0.2s linear",
                }}
              >
                <EditArrow />
              </span>
            </TeamPage>
            {openAgreement && (
              <Agreement
                teamData={teamData}
                agreement={agreement}
                editable={editable}
                teamId={teamId}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
                notify={notify}
              />
            )}
            <TeamPage onClick={() => setOpenCalendar(!openCalendar)}>
              Calendar
              <span
                className={classes.arrow}
                style={{
                  transform: rotateCalendar,
                  transition: "all 0.2s linear",
                }}
              >
                <EditArrow />
              </span>
            </TeamPage>
            {openCalendar && (
              <Calendar
                teamId={teamId}
                editable={editable}
                teamData={teamData}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
              />
            )}
     ...
  </div>
```

Is there anyway I can use map or create an array to map over these components?
I think there must be a way to make my code shorter, hoping get some suggestions, thanks~

Comment: I think you are not duplicating code the code is fine, you have different components with the same `props` this is where it looks like we are repeating ourselves. You can go with this approach but a little modification you can do with you code just compute the value when required for `rotate`, `rotateAgreement`, `rotateCalendar` don't store them in a variable this is something that is not neccessary just compute them when required like instead of doing `transform: rotate` you could do `transform: openMission ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)"`

Comment: If the code works as is, and you want a review of all of your code, you may want to check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question can be made on topic for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TeamPage` can handle its own state, show the children or not.

```
const TeamPage = ({title, children}) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [showChildren, setShowChildren] = useState(false);
      const rotate = showChildren ? "rotate(90deg)" : "rotate(0)";
    
      return (
            <div onClick={() => setShowChildren(!showChildren)}>
              {title}
              <span
                className={classes.arrow}
                style={{ transform: rotate, transition: "all 0.2s linear" }}
              >
                <EditArrow />
              </span>
              {showChildren ? children : null}
            </div>
       );
```

And when you use is, pass the content as the children, like this:

```
    const MobileManagement = (props) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const {
        editable,
        teamId,
        agreement,
        teamData,
        fetchTeamData,
        userPublicId,
        members,
        notify,
      } = props;
    
      return (
        <div className={classes.mobileContainer}>
          <TeamOption>
            <TeamPage title='Mission'>
              <Mission
                editable={editable}
                teamId={teamId}
                teamData={teamData}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
                notify={notify}
              />
            </TeamPage>
            <TeamPage title='Agreement'>
              <Agreement
                teamData={teamData}
                agreement={agreement}
                editable={editable}
                teamId={teamId}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
                notify={notify}
              />
            </TeamPage>
            <TeamPage title='Calendar'>
              <Calendar
                teamId={teamId}
                editable={editable}
                teamData={teamData}
                fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
              />
            </TeamPage>
     ...
  </div>
```